# Best way to create and restore a Drive Image with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, disk-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to create a system image](https://superuser.com/questions/92224/want-to-create-a-system-image)

I am about to build a new PC.  I am a windows 7 user.  For years now I have been wanting to  install windows and all my favorite software, music, etc., and then make a drive IMAGE and be able to go in 6 months later or WHENEVER I want to start fresh and completely format my drives and restore my IMAGE and have all my settings, programs, etc be just5 like when I created the original image.

I know there is many ways to do this but I have never done this 100% successfully and I have about a week to figure out how to do it perfectly for when I build my new PC.

I have heard good things about using tried Acronis true image in the PAST for doing what I describe4, I tried using it but, but the newer versions are overly complex and don't even seem to work the way I hoped.

I also see that Windows 7 has some sort of drive IMAGE creator itself as well.  Does the newer Windows 7 image creator do what I am describing above?  If it does do what I am asking for (complete drive image with windows, all programs and settings) saved to an IMAGE file that can easily be restored to ANY hard drive in the future?

Please share your experiences, tips, ideas on how to achieve this the easiest and most reliable way please

Comment: possible duplicate (one of many): http://superuser.com/questions/92224/want-to-create-a-system-image

Answer (score 2):

For me, definitly [Norton GHost](http://www.symantec.com/index.jsp)

Easy to create restor and easier to backup. #1 for me!

Comment: With Norton Ghost, let's say I bought a new hardrive or drives and put them in a NEW PC and I have an image previously created with NG.  Will I need to first install windows, then install Norton Ghost, then have it install my Image?  Hopefully it has a better method?

Comment: You can create a Norton Image with a boot disk by example. You do a "disk-to-disk" and then you can restore. Install Sysprep and make sure you have a new SSID. Also, you can install Windows and just restore your files with the wizard. easy easy easy!