# Best way to create a system image restore partition?

Tags: windows-7, backup, partitioning, multi-boot, boot-partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to create a system image](https://superuser.com/questions/92224/want-to-create-a-system-image)
>   [Best way to create and restore a Drive Image with Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/111409/best-way-to-create-and-restore-a-drive-image-with-windows-7)

What are some options for creating a partition containing a cloned copy of the system partition for future restore/recovery purposes?

How would I protect those files from being written to?

I'm trying to figure out best ways for a netbook, potentially something that includes a utility that may be accessed from the boot menu for restores of the system.

Answers to any of the above questions acceptable.

Windows 7 32-bit. No optical drive

Comment: What OS are you looking to do this for? If Windows Vista/7, look into their built in software. Using your DVD, you can boot and restore to a particular backup. Are you wanting an incremental backup system? Look into CloneZilla for a one time deal.

Comment: Sorry, yes, Windows 7 32bit. No optic drive, so preferably solutions that are stored in a seperate partition.

Comment: I would recommend a different hard drive instead of a different partition. If your hard drive dies then you will have no backups.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the system recovery partitions found on many OEM systems these days? Where you can select to boot from that partition and it'll take you through an automated recovery process?

Comment: @Mokubai, this question differs because he's asking about creating a recovery partition, not a full image on a set of disks or a separate drive.

Comment: The tools are still relevant, you can basically use them to make your own recovery partition.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick Google search returned a least 2 tutorials from major and legitimate sites (pcmag and lifehacker and computing.net) on how to do this: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+system+recovery+partition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

PCMag: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2014353,00.asp